# How to combine JSF + templates + Html 5 cache?

Tags: html, jsf, caching, jsf-2, browser-cache

In my JSF app all pages use a master template. The template includes a header which shows the company logo. I would like to use Html cache manifest to tell the browser to cache that image on the client side.

I have tried to add the `manifest` attribute to the template's html tag:

```
<html
    lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    manifest="myapp.appcache">

<h:head>
// ...
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="main">
        <ui:insert name="mainContent" />
    </div>
</h:body>

</html>
```

And created the **myapp.appcache** at the root of my app.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/myapp/images/logo.png
```

I have run some tests by loading the page a few times and checking the *Network* tab on Chrome's Dev tool, and I could notice that a GET request is always triggered for the logo.png resource.

I'm not sure how to debug this, I'm kinda new to the whole Html 5 stuff.

I have tried to move the myapp.appcache file to same directory as my template's, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with another browser?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. It can't be a compatibility issue, since I've tested this feature on the W3C showcase